# Error occurs while adding platform in cordova project

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ubuntu

I have created on Cordova project but while adding platform it gives me following error:

```
dev@dny:~/AngularCordova/13_12_2017/myApp$ cordova platform add android
```

Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.3.0

**Error:**

```
Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~6.3.0
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: cordova-android@~6.3.0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/dny/.npm/_logs/2017-12-13T09_52_01_436Z-debug.log
```

Comment: what `npm` version do u use? what `cordova` version?

Comment: npm is 5.4.2 and cordova is 7.1.0

Comment: @dny I tried with cordova 7.1.0 and android version 6.3.0, it works fine. Only difference i could see is that my node version 6.9.2 Just try out with latest node version and ensure that your network connection is proper

Answer (score 0):

`npm install -g android@latest`

solved this problem for me.

Also updated android Cordova is using with

```
'npm install -g cordova-android'
```